# How did I get a number from a substitution on a non-numeric string?

Tags: perl, activeperl

I'm new in perl and have a little problem:

part of perl code:

```
print "${data_dir}\n";
#converting directory path to unix format (replacing all backslashes with slashes)
$data_dir = ~s/\\/\//g;
print "${data_dir}\n";
```

output:

```
C:/dev/../data
4294967295
```

Why results are different? I guess that the problem in `$data_dir` variable, because this works for other string, but what can be the problem?

P.S. `$data_dir` I'm getting from other module, and don't know how it is constructed.

Comment: you may find it clearer to use another character to define the regex so that you don't need to escape the forward-slash, e.g. `$data_dir =~ s{\\}{/}g;` - use the same principle as q, qw, qq etc and pick a (sensible) character that doesn't appear within the string

Comment: @Axeman Why did you edit title of question? Now I can't understand it :))) And thing that people who have such problem will not search in google phrase "How do I get a number from a substitution on a non-numeric string?"

Comment: quite simply, your question was wrong. The substitution wasn't "spoiling" the variable, the assignment you mistakenly typed was. Plus, my phrasing is, I dare say, a little more symptomatic than the conclusion you jumped to.

Comment: they would probably never search for your question either, unless they thought a variable was "spoiled". 1) You (thought you) were doing a substitution operation, the result was a numeric string when you started out with a non-numeric string. These elements are more likely to be searched on than 's with g' -- when the global flag had nothing to do with it, and you would have gotten a similar result without the global flag. I tried to capture the "anomaly" without prejudicial words. So I kept it to input, operation, and output.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a space between the = and the ~.   They should be together =~.

```
$data_dir =~ s/\\/\//g;
```

What you were doing is setting $data_dir equal to the complement (i.e. the ~ operator) of `s/\\/\//g` which equals 4294967295.

Answer (score 3):

Is that really "= ~" with a space in it?

It should be "=~" with no space. You are currently assigning $data_dir the bitwise negated value of the string.

Your are using the following aren't you?

use strict;
use warnings;

Answer (score 2):

Others have already answered with the cause of the problem - the space between `= ~`, which should have been `=~` without the space.

A valuable lesson is to always add `use strict` to your scripts; if you'd done so, you would have received a warning like:

```
Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///) at (eval 11) line 4.
```

That would have helped you to figure out that the substitution operator was being used on `$_` rather than on `$data_dir` - because instead of the binding operator `=~` binding it to `$data_dir`, you had `= ~`.

So, lesson to learn: always `use strict` - it'll help catch things like this, where you could have a single character wrong, and save you a lot of time.

Incidentally, when working with file paths and desiring portability between platforms, using [File::Spec](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Spec) is often a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you apply a numeric operator (~) to s/..../g.
Try the following:

```
$data_dir =~  s/...../g;
```